# Rewriting adminhtml block

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, overrides

I'm attempting to rewrite `protected function _prepareColumns()` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`

I have created the class `MyCompany_Overrides_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid`, extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid`, with the following in the `config.xml`:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
         <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_grid>MyCompany_Overrides_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

However, the rewrite function is not being hit, but instead the original function is hit.

Could anyone point out any obvious flaws in the setup?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not using the right namespace, it should be `adminhtml` instead of `catalog`

```
<global>
    <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_grid>MyCompany_Overrides_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```